# What jQuery plugins should be incorporated into jQuery or jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery plugins are great, except this is about a billion or so of them<sup>1</sup>, and most of them however will fade into the background noise of the rest. What are those plugins that are so useful that they should be incorporated into jQuery or jQueryUI (if it's a UI/effect type) or included in a jQuery bundle?

<sub>1- billion is just a rough estimate</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of agree with Cletus, but instead of taking the hardline keeps it super tight, why now have a third "jQuery Essentials" and include things like JavascriptServerTemplates in it.  The good thing about having such a package is that it could focus the effort on things so that there aren't 19 ways to do a section of a page that turns into a button when you mouse over it, just one that works.

Some guy is aparently trying to create this - http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html;

Answer (score 13):

None. The reason jQuery is good is because it is lightweight and extensible.

Answer (score 1):

bgiframe should be included with jQuery UI to help with dialogs and ie6

see: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Dialog#option-bgiframe

Answer (score 1):

Textbox hinting would be a very nice addition to jQuery UI. Something like [coolinput](http://code.google.com/p/coolinput/)

Answer (score 0):

I find [Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) very useful in almost any project.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have Filament Group's Menu plugin in JQueryUI